# Disable shortcut target field

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, file-shortcut, autoit

I am using AutoIT to create shortcut to desktop and also will forced to launch as kiosk by adding the parameter at the end of the target field. But how can I disable the target field from editing when creating shortcut?

Please kindly advise.

**EDIT**

[Window Explorer View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUdZX.png)

[Permission Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF6iZ.png)

Comment: What is "editing"?

Comment: Meaning that I create a shortcut at desktop and adding the parameters to launch as kiosk mode. After this process, I don't want any other users to edit the target path to remove the kiosk mode.

Comment: Set it to read only, or edit the permissions to only allow modify to your account.

Comment: Already tried to set the permission to the folder or the chrome portable application before I create shortcut to desktop. But the user able to edit the target field value at dekstop

Answer (score 0):

You could make the shortcut (or a batch file) in a location the user cannot access, where only Administrator has write-access. Then make a shortcut to *that shortcut* and put it on the desktop, verifying that non-admin users can *execute* it. You may need to change permissions on the first shortcut to ensure Read and Execute permission for all.

[image: Read-Execute permission]

Comment: It still able to edit the shortcut tho. I did try set the permission to read & execute only, then create the shortcut to desktop. But at desktop, I am still able to edit the target path. Will edit the my post by adding image.

Comment: "It still able to edit the shortcut tho." **Which of the two shortcuts** are you discussing? Did you log in as a non-Admin user?

Comment: Please kindly assume there is don't have admin user, there is only 1 user in the device. The scenario would like this, I will create PortableChrome.exe to desktop as shortcut, then right-click the shortcut and edit the target field to launch as Kiosk mode. After this, I want to lock the target field from being modify (like Grey Out)